# List only unique users

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird1.5

Table is `users`, columns are `user_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `area`.

The other table is `user_sessions`, and columns are `user_id`, `logon`, `logoff`.

To see who is logged on I use

```
select u.FIRSTNAME, u.LASTNAME, u.PHONE_ID, us.LOGON 
from USERS u 
    join USER_sessions us on u.USER_ID=us.user_id 
where cast (us.LOGON as date) = date 'now' 
and us.LOGOFF is null 
order by u.FIRSTNAME
```

The result is correct, but sometimes I get duplicated entries.

For example, same `firstname` and `lastname`, but different logon. I'd like to only see the latest logon.

Comment: What is the data type of `LOGON`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like field `LOGON` is kind of a timestamp type field; your question is not really precise, there.

So, I think, you want the maximum value of `LOGON`. For that, there is an aggregate function `MAX()` which has to be used with a `GROUP BY`.

```
select u.FIRSTNAME, u.LASTNAME, u.PHONE_ID, MAX(us.LOGON)
  from USERS u 
  join USER_sessions us
    on u.USER_ID = us.user_id 
  where cast (us.LOGON as date) = date 'now' 
    and us.LOGOFF is null
  group by u.FIRSTNAME, u.LASTNAME, u.PHONE_ID 
  order by u.FIRSTNAME
```

You'll get the latest `LOGON` for every occurence of `u.FIRSTNAME, u.LASTNAME, u.PHONE_ID`.

Note, that you can use `current_date` context variable instead of `date 'now'` cast.

Comment: @LeoFazzi If my answer does fit your needs, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left of it.

Comment: Thank you Rene'. I wonder if I could show totals on the bottom line. Probably union and run a count of? Never tried it...

Comment: @LeoFazzi This would be a new question and has to be asked as so. But you could have a look at [`row_count`](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-row_count.html).

Comment: Cheers Rene'... will try it but not sure it will be :/